# MobileFirst Client-side Logging to write log at custom location

Tags: logging, adapter, client-side, ibm-mobilefirst

Working with MFPv7.0 - IF201601311728

I have developed a **WLClientLogReceiver** JavaScript Adapter. I define the (mandatory) `log` procedure and do the following:

1. Specify a path to a directory in `worklight.properties` (dir)
2. Read that value using `WL.Server.configuration("<property>")`
3. Escape to java to

   - open a `java.util.logging.Logger` instance
   - Set a `java.util.logging.FileHandler` for file using the above `Logger` instance and the path (dir) read.
4. Log to that dir/file using the logger's methods [like `info()`, `debug()`... etc.]

After doing that, I do not see the log entries in the dir/file location.

Any pointers on what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Do you though any errors in the default (and only) log file that is typically used: messages.log?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge you cannot do this change. Instead perhaps it would be easier for you to use the MobileFirst Analytics console which is able to handle this and present this information in a visual (and textual) manner.